# Is there a way to complete or terminate Nginx-Gunicorn-Flask request if client abandons the call?

Tags: nginx, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I have an API application that's layered as follows `nginx -> gunicorn (gevent) -> Flask (Flask-Sqlalchemy)`. Nginx comes from hosting on Google App Engine Flex.

Flask-Sqlalchemy commits at the end of every request (implicit commit) so new request begins with a different transaction.

I've been running into an issue where a request that modifies a record gets stuck sometimes and prevents other requests from completing because they too are stuck trying to acquire lock to the modified record.

After troubleshooting, I identified the issue as client disconnecting and 'abandoning' the request (499 reported by Nginx). When abandoned, the flask request doesn't complete and records holding locks linger for 300s as there is no implicit commit. These requests don't normally take more than 5s to complete but abandoned requests finish at 300s which is the gunicorn timeout.

Gunicorn timeout can't be modified at the moment as the same application server servers long-running backend tasks.

Is there a way to make Flask, Flask-SqlAlchemy specifically, complete the request and there by run implicit commit if the request has been abandoned instead of waiting 300s?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Gunicorn with async workers do not terminate the request if client disconnects. Gunicorn continues to process the request until it's finished.

More discussion about this [here](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/1730#issuecomment-375658620).